# Replace "\\" with "\" in a path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

The *File.WriteAllBytes* function works fine @"\" in the path input

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\folder\file.png", bytes);
```

but with "\\"

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\folder\\file.png", bytes);
```

returns : **The given path's format is not supported**

In my application I have something like that

```
 File.WriteAllBytes(getFile(fid), bytes);
```

where getFile(fid) returns

> C:\\folder\\fileid.png

So I've tryied getFile(fid).Replace("\\",@"\").. I was expecting this

> C:\folder\fileid.png

but I still have this

> C:\\folder\\fileid.png

and the error **The given path's format is not supported**

Comment: your replace method should be Replace("\\\\","\\") this Edited replace method

Comment: Your first two lines of code are identical, it's not possible that the second one fails if the first one works.

Comment: Maybe there are unsupported characters in the filename returned by getFile(fid)?! Like colons etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `getFile(fid).Replace("\\",@"\")`, `"\\"` evaluates to `\` (the first `\` serves as an escape character, to escape the second character which is the actual `\`). `@"\"` *also* evaluates to `\`. Net, your code tries to replace `\` by `\` which doesn't do anything.

Instead, try `getFile(fid).Replace(@"\\",@"\")`. This should do what you want.

Comment: Or `getFile(fid).Replace("\\\\","\\")`

Comment: @Frederik Carlier it stills returns C:\\folder\\fileid.png with .Replace(@"\\",@"\")

Comment: @RandRandom it stills returns C:\\folder\\fileid.png with with .Replace("\\\\","\\");

Comment: @ptiflo are you looking at the debugger, validating that string? if so, the debugger will display \ as \\ - as you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOUwi.png - but it is in fact just a single \

Comment: @ptiflo - here see an extended screenshot with with single or double \ - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzuqr.png